# Python: How can I use bottle to get a certain url from the local host?

Tags: python, authentication, oauth, spotify, bottle

I am trying to do the Authorization code flow for Spotify, I open the local host using bottle, then go the authorization page, after that I get directed to a page with the access_token in the url. How can I use bottle (or any other library) to get that url (it's the 3rd page load after the starting localhost page and the giving permission to Spotify as a user page).

I tried using Selenium but when it automates the browser to open the localhost page it doesn't load and I don't even see bottle listening to the port.

I tried even applying a sleep before running the function that opens selenium but it did not work out

My code is as follows:

````
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from spotipy import oauth2
from bottle import route, run, request
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import urllib


client_id = ''
client_secret = ''
port_number = 8080
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/callback'
scope = 'user-read-recently-played'
method = 'GET'

# getting the token following the Authorization code flow - the user will grant permission for the app to use their data.


def get_lookup_url():
    auth_url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
    auth_data = {
        'client_id': f'{client_id}',
        'response_type': 'code',
        'redirect_uri': f'{redirect_uri}',
        'scope': f'{scope}'
    }

    encoded_auth_data = urlencode(auth_data)

    lookup_url = f'{auth_url}?{encoded_auth_data}'
    # r = requests.get(lookup_url)
    return lookup_url
    # print(lookup_url)
    # print(r.status_code)
    # print(r.text)


# helper function to get the access toekn from the url
def get_access_token_from_url():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/****/****/chromedriver')
    driver.get(redirect_uri)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds - enough time for me to login to spotify and click the agree button
    # urllib.request.urlopen(redirect_uri)
    access_token_split = ''
    current_url = ''
    # current_url = driver.current_url
    print(current_url) # TODO remove this line later
    if 'access_token' in current_url:
        split = current_url.split('#')
        print(split[1]) # getting what's after the '#'
        split_again = split[1].split('&')
        print(split_again) # TODO remove this line later
        for i in split_again:
            if 'access_token' in i:
                access_token_split = i.split('=')
                print(access_token_split) # TODO remove this line later
        return access_token_split[1]


# login button goes to the lookup url
@route('/callback')
def html_login_button():
    auth_url = get_lookup_url() # assigning the function to a variable
    htmlLoginButton = "<a id='login' href='" + auth_url + "'>Login to Spotify</a>"
    return htmlLoginButton

# time.sleep(10)
# looking for the access_token in the url
get_access_token_from_url()

run(host='', port=port_number, debug=True) # opens at http://localhost:8080/callback```
````

Comment: Why do you think you need a web server (Bottle) to be an oauth client?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use Chrome to fetch urls, instead of `requests`?

Comment: I use bottle cuz I have to have a redirect_uri to click agree and then get redirected again to that redirect_uri page to get the auth_code in the url. And if by your chrome question you mean selenium with chrome then I actually decided to not use selenium. Do you think there's another way to get the auth (I mean without a webserver)?

Comment: You don't need a web server. Use an http client (like `requests`) and it will follow redirects.